# How does AD interpret XML strings? E.g. New line in address field?

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory

I am currently working on a PowerShell module which will simplify our account creation process in our org. I have company address details in a .ps1xml file.

The account gets created however the new line in the address field does not come across correctly.

I have tried the following;

```
- Using &#xD; (Carriage return)
- Using &#10;
- Using &#13;
```

So like this:

```
<Street>ADDRESS LINE 1 &#xD; ADDRESS LINE 2</Street>
```

AD Object is populated like so:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Users\saturner\Desktop\Scripts\Modules\Accounts\Accounts.ps1xml'
$xmlpath = $xml.Sites

$street = $xmlpath.Office | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Street

New-ADUser -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName -DisplayName "$FirstName $LastName" -Title $Title -StreetAddress $street -UserPrincipalName "$username@contoso.org" -PostalCode $postcode -State $state -Country $country -Manager $ManagerUsername -Fax $fax -City $city -Company $company -Office $OfficeLocation -HomePage $webpage -Description $script:description -OfficePhone $tel -Name "$FirstName $LastName" -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -Path $OU -Department $Department -AccountExpirationDate $EndDate -Server $script:adserver
```

None seem to interpret correctly into the AD object, but they do work when I Out-File to a .txt. Is it something to do with how AD interprets xml strings?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: Please edit the question and show how AD attribute is populated.

Comment: added as requested, ignore other variables, they are assigned earlier on in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a text field, it will populate it with exactly what you give it. But testing it, it seems it needs both the `\r` and the `\n` to display properly in the AD gui.

```bsh
$user = Get-ADUser ...
$address = "First`r`nSecond"
$user | Set-ADUser -StreetAddress $address
```

So in your XML you probably need `&#13` AND `&#10`. (Probably don't want the extra spaces at the end of the first line and at the start of the second line)

```
<Street>ADDRESS LINE 1&#13;&#10;ADDRESS LINE 2</Street>
```

How I found this out was creating a multiline street address, and then checking the character codes for every character in the string:

```bsh
$address = (Get-ADUser ... -Properties streetAddress).StreetAddress
0..$address.Length | % { Write-Host "$($address[$_]) $([int32]$address[$_])" }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much, was face-desking on this one yesterday!